# 形 at end of verbs

Tags: grammar, word-choice, suffixes

I know that 形 can be used as a suffix meaning shape that I understand but I don't seem to understand what it's used after a verb like in this sentence.

とりあえず こっちでやることを 絞り それを**検討する形**のほうが

Comment: Relevant entry from 研究社　新和英大辞典　第５版:

2 〔物事の状態・傾向〕 a state; conditions; a tendency.
►その問題で両党が協力する形ができあがった.　That problem led to ┏both [the two] parties cooperating. ｜ It came about that ┏both [the two] parties would cooperate on that issue.

Comment: The phrasing of the question makes me wonder if you've learned how relative clauses work. Is it something you're familiar with generally? If that's not part of the confusion, then you can ignore this.